# Configuration Type: Application.exe to Static Library Error

Tags: visual-c++-2013

I need help, my first error is this **"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_getinfo referenced in function"**, but I already solve this after I change the configuration type from .exe to static library in project properties but when I try to build the project I get this runtime error. **"This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel"**. That error is pointing to "projectname.lib" in my project debug folder.

I'm using Visual C++ 2013 and I'm building win32 Application and I'm using libcurl for REST.

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably still have your .lib file project set as the startup project. The IDE is complaining that you're trying to execute your .lib file, and since it's not executable, and there are no apps registered that take .lib files as documents, it can't. That's okay, you don't want to execute it, you just want to build it. You can change the solution so you build the app project that uses the library as the startup project, and have it build the library as a dependency.